# Place all the metadata in a Path in Spring SAML

Tags: spring, spring-security, saml-2.0, spring-saml, opensaml

I have this implementation of Spring Saml. I'm planning to discover all IDP metadata in 1 location and discover it automatically without defining a new `ExtendedMetadataDelegate` bean in security-context.xml. Is that achievable?

```
<b:bean id="metadata" class="org.springframework.security.saml.metadata.CachingMetadataManager">
        <b:constructor-arg >
           <b:list>
               <b:bean class="org.springframework.security.saml.metadata.ExtendedMetadataDelegate">
                   <b:constructor-arg >
                       <b:bean class="org.opensaml.saml2.metadata.provider.FilesystemMetadataProvider">
                           <b:constructor-arg>
                               <b:value type="java.io.File">${idp.one.metadata.file.path}</b:value>
                           </b:constructor-arg>
                           <b:property name="parserPool" ref="parserPool"/>
                       </b:bean>
                   </b:constructor-arg >
                   <b:constructor-arg >
                       <b:bean class="org.springframework.security.saml.metadata.ExtendedMetadata">
                       </b:bean>
                   </b:constructor-arg >
               </b:bean>

               <b:bean class="org.springframework.security.saml.metadata.ExtendedMetadataDelegate">
                   <b:constructor-arg >
                       <b:bean class="org.opensaml.saml2.metadata.provider.FilesystemMetadataProvider">
                           <b:constructor-arg>
                               <b:value type="java.io.File">${idp.two.metadata.file.path}</b:value>
                           </b:constructor-arg>
                           <b:property name="parserPool" ref="parserPool"/>
                       </b:bean>
                   </b:constructor-arg >
                   <b:constructor-arg >
                       <b:bean class="org.springframework.security.saml.metadata.ExtendedMetadata">
                       </b:bean>
                   </b:constructor-arg >
               </b:bean>

               <b:bean class="org.springframework.security.saml.metadata.ExtendedMetadataDelegate">
                   <b:constructor-arg >
                       <b:bean class="org.opensaml.saml2.metadata.provider.FilesystemMetadataProvider">
                           <b:constructor-arg>
                               <b:value type="java.io.File">${sdp.metadata.file.path}</b:value>
                           </b:constructor-arg>
                           <b:property name="parserPool" ref="parserPool"/>
                       </b:bean>
                   </b:constructor-arg >
                   <b:constructor-arg >
                       <b:bean class="org.springframework.security.saml.metadata.ExtendedMetadata">
                           <b:property name="local" value="true"/>
                           <b:property name="alias" value="default"/>
                           <b:property name="securityProfile" value="metaiop"/>
                           <b:property name="sslSecurityProfile" value="pkix"/>
                           <b:property name="signingKey" value="test"/>
                           <b:property name="encryptionKey" value="test"/>
                           <b:property name="requireArtifactResolveSigned" value="false"/>
                           <b:property name="requireLogoutRequestSigned" value="false"/>
                           <b:property name="requireLogoutResponseSigned" value="false"/>
                           <b:property name="idpDiscoveryEnabled" value="false"/>
                       </b:bean>
                   </b:constructor-arg >
               </b:bean>
           </b:list>
        </b:constructor-arg >
</b:bean>
```

Comment: I suggest you start using the new SAML 2.0 Support that is inside the Spring Security project since the `spring-security-saml` project is reaching [EOL on Oct 6th](https://spring.io/blog/2020/09/22/spring-security-saml-extensions-1-x-eol-on-october-6-2021).

Comment: @MarcusHertdaCoregio will my problem be resolved if I used that?

Comment: Using the out-of-box SAML 2.0 support in Spring Security, you can expose a bean of `RelyingPartyRegistrationRepository` and you can have your own strategy to find the metadata.

Comment: @MarcusHertdaCoregio does it supports Http-Artifact Binding?